# How can Python execute a line of code, then display an error indicating a crash at the previous line?

Tags: python, pytorch, pdb, tqdm

I have a script which contains (among other things) these three lines of code:

```
(line 138) pdb.set_trace()

(line 140) training_start_time = datetime.now()
(line 141) print(f'Network training beginning at {training_start_time}.')
```

Here is the output I'm seeing:

```
> c:\vtcproject\yolov5\roadometry_train.py(140)train()
-> training_start_time = datetime.now()
(Pdb) >? continue
Network training beginning at 2022-02-17 11:23:04.340499.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alexander Farley\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\212.5457.59\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Alexander Farley\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\212.5457.59\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_train.py", line 316, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_train.py", line 304, in main
    train(data, cfg, hyp, opt, device)
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_train.py", line 140, in train
    training_start_time = datetime.now()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

There are a few things I don't understand here.

1. How is it possible to see this print output (network training beginning at...) if the code is crashing at `datetime.now()`?
2. Why is it that if I manually execute `dt = datetime.now()` in pdb, then it works fine, but I'm seeing `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` if I type `continue` into pdb or just execute the script without pdb?

The library is imported like this:

```
(line 13) from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: Somewhere you your script you're assigning something to `datetime.now`

Comment: @Barmar just did a ctrl-f fow datetime.now in my entire project and I can't see anything, but I will look for something along these lines.

Comment: Search for other uses of `now`

Comment: @Barmar just checked every occurrence of `now` using a loose match, no assignments to this variable.

Comment: @Barmar another strange thing is that it seems to be crashing on the very next line. I will try some divide-and-conquer to see if I can simplify things. The way I'm reading it, there shouldn't be any opportunity for my code to overwrite datetime.now.

Comment: Somehow `datetime.now` is a module name, not the function name. Look for uses that aren't assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this turned out to be somewhat complicated.

I removed code from my script until I found something very strange. Further down my script, below the lines listed above, I was eventually entering a loop which created an instance of `tqdm` for progress updates:

```
for epoch in range(start_epoch,
                   opt.epochs):
    pbar = enumerate(train_loader)
    pbar = tqdm(pbar, total=nb)  # progress bar
```

When I commented out the `tqdm` usage in the loop, the TypeError above (at line 140, according to the exception) disappeared.

Paring everything down reinforced that simply calling `tqdm` caused this error. Searching the `tqdm` Github issues, I found this:

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/611

There is a post in this discussion indicating that `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` can occur if one uses:

```
import tqdm
```

instead of:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

So my analysis of what happened here is that `tqdm` was simply imported as a module, and obviously calling a module as a new object instance isn't going to work. The only confusing part is why the stated line-number is wrong.

The issue raised on Github corresponds closely to my scenario: creating a PyTorch `dataloader` which is then passed to `tqdm`.

I was basing my code on the Ultralytics Yolov5 repo and it appears that I changed `from tqdm import tqdm` to just `import tqdm` mistakenly. Specifically importing the class and not just the module causes the TypeError to disappear.

It seems that this error has nothing to do with `datetime.now()`. After commenting this out, I still get a `TypeError`, but pointing at a different line - now it blames the actual line trying to create a `tqdm` instance, which is what I would have expected in the first place.

```
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_debug.py", line 41, in train
    for epoch in range(start_epoch,
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

In the above output, line 41 of `roadometry_debug.py` is:

```
    pbar = tqdm(pbar, total=nb)  # progress bar
```

While the line number being blamed appears correct, it seems that the error printout is still printing out the wrong line: `for epoch in range...`.

This explains why `pdb` allows me to manually execute the next line, and the next print-out: because they're not the issue!

I still don't understand why the first error text blames the wrong line of code, or why the 2nd error text prints out the wrong text but the correct line-number.

---

Update: it seems that `pdb` is causing the reported line numbers in the error message to be incorrect.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import pdb
import tqdm
from datetime import datetime


def train():

    pdb.set_trace()

    training_start_time = datetime.now()
    print(f'Network training beginning at {training_start_time}.')

    for epoch in range(0,
                       10):  # epoch ------------------------------------------------------------------
        pbar = enumerate([1, 2, 3])
        pbar = tqdm(pbar, total=3)  # progress bar


def main():
    train()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error message printed out from the above blames the wrong line:

```
c:\vtcproject\yolov5\roadometry_debug.py(10)train()
-> training_start_time = datetime.now()
(Pdb) >? continue
Network training beginning at 2022-02-17 18:32:13.892776.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alexander Farley\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\212.5457.59\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Alexander Farley\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\212.5457.59\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_debug.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_debug.py", line 20, in main
    train()
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_debug.py", line 10, in train
    training_start_time = datetime.now()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

If the call to `pdb.set_trace()` is commented out, the error message blames the correct line.

Script after commenting out relevant line:

```
import pdb
import tqdm
from datetime import datetime


def train():

    #pdb.set_trace()

    training_start_time = datetime.now()
    print(f'Network training beginning at {training_start_time}.')

    for epoch in range(0,
                       10):  # epoch ------------------------------------------------------------------
        pbar = enumerate([1, 2, 3])
        pbar = tqdm(pbar, total=3)  # progress bar


def main():
    train()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Network training beginning at 2022-02-17 18:33:31.278133.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alexander Farley\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\212.5457.59\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Alexander Farley\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\212.5457.59\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_debug.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_debug.py", line 20, in main
    train()
  File "C:/VTCProject/yolov5/roadometry_debug.py", line 16, in train
    pbar = tqdm(pbar, total=3)  # progress bar
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Notice that the final line-number in the error printout has now changed from **10** (incorrect) to **16** (correct).

It's a reverse heisenbug - only appears if observed!